# Dominated convergence theorem: Each $f_n$ have to be integrable in the assumption?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The Dominated Convergence Theorem on Wikipedia does not assume each $f_n$ to be integrable (although it turns out they have to). However, the same theorem appears in Dudley's book seems to require $f_n$ to be integrable in the first place.

> Let $f_n$ and $g$ be in $\mathcal{L}^1 \left(X,S,\mu\right)$, $\left|f_n(x)\right| \le g(x)$ and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$. Then $f\in\mathcal{L}^1$ and $\int f_n\,d\mu \to \int f \,d\mu$.

Is Dudley's book making a stronger-than-usual assumption?

As for why I am interested. It is true that if $\int |f|\,d\mu <\infty$, then $\int f \,d\mu <\infty$ and is well-defined. If we do not require $f$ to be integrable in the assumption, then simply consider $f\to f$ and it is dominated by $|f|$, which is integrable. So $\int f \,d\mu$ is integrable. But if we add the assumption that each $f_n$ needs to be integrable, then we cannot invoke this theorem in this problem. Another situation is where I want to explain if $|f| < M$, then it is integrable. I guess in both case I can go back to writing $f$ as $f^+ - f^-$, but just curious on how to use DCT.

Comment: Each $f_n$ is integrable because it is a measurable function such that $\int |f_n| \le \int g < \infty$.

Comment: @user296602 I think that is what I'm trying to show. No?

Comment: @iseliget Because, each $f_n$ is dominated by an integrable $g$, thus by comparison theorem, $f_n$ is integrable. It is an immediate consequence of the domination hypothesis.  Also, I don't understand what do you mean by "we cannot invoke this theorem in this problem", in _which_ problem, under what assumptions, in order to do what? Usually, DCT requires only some regularity conditions on each $f_n$.

Comment: @Raito I want to show that if $\int |f| \,d\mu < \infty$, then $\int f \,d\mu <\infty$. Let $f_n = f$, then obviously $f_n \to f$ By DCT on Wiki, since $f_n$ (which is really just $f$) is dominated by $|f|$, we conclude that $\int f \,d\mu <\infty$. However, if I use DCT in the quote, I run into trouble because it requires $f$ to be integrable, which is what I'm trying to show.

Comment: @Raito which puzzles me because the DCT that I know does not requite each $f_n$ to be integrable.

Comment: @iseliget Why do you use DCT for this basic property? Why not use $\lvert f \rvert ^{+}$ and $\lvert f \rvert^{-}$ like you mention it in your post? But, anyway, one version of DCT allows you to prove it this way, another version with a stricter hypothesis does not allow you to prove it this way. Either way, you should try to understand what DCT requires to be proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement of $f_n$ to be integrable is irrelevant, because the hypothesis $|f_n|\leq g$ with $g$ integrable implies that $f_n$ is integrable. This is because for a positive function its integral is either finite or infinite, but always exists.

For a non-positive function $f$, for its Lebesgue integral to be defined we need that at least one $f_+$ and $f_-$ (its positive and negative parts) is integrable. Then, by definition, if $|f|$ is integrable then so is $f$.

For your final example, bounded implies integrable only on a finite measure space. But, in that case, again you don't need DCT but only the definition of "integrable".

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall read on this topic more deeply. As a statistics student, we almost always deal with probability space which is finite measure space. Probably that's the point I was missing.